# Editing UINavigationBar translucence adds padding on bottom

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin

I've been developing with Xamarin and iOS for about two weeks now, and currently I'm attempting to figure out why a strange bug is happening. I've looked all over Google and even SO, but can't find an answer...one that works, anyways. As the title says, whenever I change the `Translucent` boolean property of my `NavigationController.NavigationBar`, extra padding is added for seemingly no reason. This can be seen in the image below:[image]

The line of code I use for this is `this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.Translucent = false;` and without that line, the application looks like this:
[image]

Other than that line, the `NavigationController.NavigationBar` is unedited. So, does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated...thanks SO!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the way how you construct your views and their containments.
Make sure that [EdgesForExtendedLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/UIKit.UIViewController.EdgesForExtendedLayout/) ([Apple Docu](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621515-edgesforextendedlayout)) has the right value. I would suggest UIRectEdge.All.

In the case you are using a scrollView als check the [automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin) property.

Comment: Thanks for the response; over the past few minutes I've been trying `this.NavigationController.` and `this.` for each method (`AutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets`, `EdgesForExtendedLayout`) but editing either, both, or any of those properties does nothing for me. I've also tried `UIRectEdge.None` for the `EdgesForExtendedLayout` property...interesting problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually figured out through posting on the Xamarin Forums and browsing through [their documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/navigation_controller/change_the_nav_bar_transparency/) that the UINavigationBar.Translucent property adjusts the view if you turn it off such that all of the screen's contents are visible beneath the now-opaque UINavigationBar. I was simply placing the UI elements with unnecessarily large Y-values because I was unaware of the screen change after `.Translucent = false;`

I changed the `.Frame = new CGRect(x, y, w, h)` properties of each UI element with respect to 0 being right below the navigation bar, not underneath it.